# Unable to render state, but can console.log it

Tags: reactjs

I have a state defined like this:

```
  state = {
    items: [
      {id: 0, value: 0},
      {id: 1, value: 0},
    ],
  };
```

when I console.log(this.state.items[0].id) in the the constructor, I get the correct value.

But when I try to render it like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
      <th id="d0" onClick={(e)=>this.onClick(e)}>{this.state.items[0].id}</th>
    ....
```

It says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Is the render happening before the state gets initialized, and therefore is undefined when it tries to render?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    /**
     * @param {object} props
     */
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: 0, value: 0 },
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
        ],
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.state.items[0].id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="d0" onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e)}>th</th>
                            <th id="d1">h</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onClick(e) {
        this.setState({ day0: 6 });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance posted

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It looks to render properly without errors. See the live snippet.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not trying to render "th", I'm trying to render this.state.items[0].id

Answer (score 2):

Your state should be set within your constructor

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [
            { id: 0, value: 0 },
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
        ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th id="d0" onClick={(e)=>this.onClick(e)}>{this.state.items[0].id}</th>
            </tr>
           </table>
         </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the state incorrectly. States should be initialized inside the constructor in class based components. Please update the state initialization as :

```
class App extends React.Component {
    /**
     * @param {object} props
     */
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [
            { id: 0, value: 0 },
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
        ],
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="d0" onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e)}>{this.state.items[0].id}</th>
                        <th id="d1">h</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

onClick(e) {
    this.setState({ day0: 6 });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```